search for partial filenames in windows 11 explorer not finding items
I am trying to search my webapps directory to find which versions of a jar I am using.
If I search for the full name (below) it finds 8 files.
jersey-atom-abdera-1.19.4

If I search for the name excluding the version number, it doesn't find a single file. Nor do any of the alternatives I learnt about in Windows 10
jersey-atom-abdera
name:jersey-atom-abdera
name:jersey-atom-abdera\


I copy and paste the same text but excluding the version number

but when i search for just jersey it works

This is the moment at which it starts working again

This is the moment it stops working


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Unclear: Just typing jersey-atom-abdera into the Search box will show you all the files that contain this string. There is no way that this can't work.

Try and copy from the file name in case you have some weird characters? file: and filename: work better for me than name:, which seems to want an exact match and not handle wildcards like * or ?

@harrymc I have added proof, it doesn't work jersey works, the full name works but a midding value doesn't

@Cpt.Whale I always do copy and paste, my typing it that unreliable.

Explorer search is known to be lousy, which is why I for example don't use it. First, it has problems searching for parts of words, and secondly, it has bugs. You have by now proven that it's so.

@harrymc okay thanks, this is just a bug, and not something I can work around.

@harrymc you just got me a bit uppity with "no way this can't work"

Excuses, I said it about jersey-atom-abdera, which I believe works fine. I use instead Everything from voidtools which is excellent, has many options and also super response time. Windows Search I turn off, as it's very wasteful in resources.

@harrymc nope it doesn't work until I get to "jersey-atom-abdera-1" I typed in each char  one at a time waiting for the response.

You can Delete and Rebuild the Windows 10 & 11 Search Index. It will take some time to complete. Not much else that you could do.

Have you tried name:~"jersey-atom-abdera*" ?

@KeithMiller that worked, why? how?

@WendyG: Quotation marks ensure that characters that have special meaning to search are interpreted literally (posibly needed for the hyphen, not sure), and the tilde ~ qualifies that to allow * and ? to be interpreted as wildcards.

This is the answer from @KeithMiller who posted a comment
name:~"jersey-atom-abdera*"

Quotation marks ensure that characters that have special meaning to search are interpreted literally (possibly needed for the hyphen, not sure), and the tilde ~ qualifies that to allow * and ? to be interpreted as wildcards.
